# in an iOS UIWebView, is it better performance to use CSS box shadow or a background image

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Does using css3 features such as box shadow cause a large performance dip in an iOS UIWebView.  If I have say a hundred rows with a hundred images, should I use background images instead to create the drop shadow border effect, or is it ok to use css box shadow on all of these elements?

Comment: It depends. Measure it, you can't decide it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

CSS on iOS is hardware accelerated so should be pretty fast